# Handle Future[Option[T]] when traversing a List

Tags: scala, future, option-type

```scala
  def getCommentIds(
      commentTargetId: Long,
      sortOrder: CommentOrderEnum): Future[Seq[CommentStatsBO]]

def getCommentDetail(commentId: Long): Future[Option[CommentDetailDTO]]

def getCommentListWithDetail(
      targetId: Long,
      sortOrder: CommentOrderEnum,
      page: Int): Future[Seq[CommentDetailDTO]] = {
    commentModel.getCommentIds(targetId, sortOrder).flatMap {
      commentStatsBOSeq =>
        Future.traverse(commentStatsBOSeq) { commentStatsBO =>
// commentDetail is a Future[Option[T]]
          val commentDetail = getCommentDetail(commentStatsBO.iId)
          commentDetail.map(commentOpt =>
            commentOpt
// merge the stat info into the comment detail
              .map(_.copy(replyCount = Some(commentStatsBO.replyCount)))
              .getOrElse(CommentDetailDTO))

        }

    }
  }

case class CommentDetailDTO(
    id: Long,
    author: JsObject,
    detail: CommentDetail,
replyCount: Option[Int] = None
)
```

Firstly, the function `getCommentIds` returns a sequence of CommentStatsBO, then traversing it and try to get detail for every comment. Here comes the question, `getCommentDetail` returns a Future which contains an option since the comment maybe not found, in this case, how to filter those ones whose option is None? I have tried `getOrElse` , but don't know how to define an empty object just like `Json.obj()` since `case class` doesn't support.
Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the future meets option will come into tragedy. Now i found future in scala is still exhaustive to programer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to do too many things at the same time, rather build the solution you need step by step.

If you do a simple `Future.traverse` using just `getCommentDetail` you will get a `Future[Seq[Option[CommentDetailDTO]]]`  which then you can `map` and use `collect` with the `Seq` to remove the `Option`

```scala
def getCommentListWithDetail(
  targetId: Long,
  sortOrder: CommentOrderEnum,
  page: Int
): Future[Seq[CommentDetailDTO]] =
  commentModel.getCommentIds(targetId, sortOrder).flatMap { commentStatsBOSeq =>
    Future.traverse(commentStatsBOSeq) { commentStatsBO =>
      getCommentDetail(commentStatsBO.iId)
    } map { commentOptionalDetails =>
      commentOptionalDetails.collect {
        case Some(commentDetail) => commentDetail
      }
    }
  }
```

Or if you use **cats**, you can use `traverseFilter`

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

def getCommentListWithDetail(
  targetId: Long,
  sortOrder: CommentOrderEnum,
  page: Int
): Future[Seq[CommentDetailDTO]] =
  commentModel.getCommentIds(targetId, sortOrder).flatMap { commentStatsBOSeq =>
    commentStatsBOSeq.traverseFilter(getCommentDetail)
  }
```

Comment: Appreciated it so much bro! Your answer is progressive, especially the latter one is so elegant and concise! Damn it, i don't have enough reputation to give a vote. Once i become rich on reputation, i would come back to your answer :)

Comment: I found `commentOptionalDetails =>
      commentOptionalDetails.collect {
        case Some(commentDetail) => commentDetail
      }` can be replaced with `commentOptionalDetails => commentOptionalDetails.flatten`. It's a more convenient way to convert `Seq[Option[T]]`  to `Seq[T]` in scala.

Comment: @BugSource no worries, I am glad it helped :) if you pick an interest in **cats** check the book _"Scala with Cats"_. - About the `flatten` you are right that works, I always forget that one because I kind of dislike that such option works; but that is just personal opinion, if you prefer that one go ahead :)

Comment: I agree with you man. It's not that the shorter the program, the happier the programmer, especially for the ones who read and maintain them.  I am new to scala, but it seems to me now scala is hard to find a balance between concise and readability. Java is more verbose but at least everyone can understand it...